# invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure error with Appium AWS-devicefarm

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I have been trying to test my app using AWS device farm.

I have both native iOS and native Android Versions.

My TestNG Tests work locally perfectly, but online I kept getting the following error on both Android and iOS:

> TEST failed: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are
>   invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
>   Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision:
>   '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09
>   13:08:06' System info: host: 'ip-10-0-221-27', ip: '10.0.221.27',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-53-generic',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_75' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDrive

My JDK is 1.8, Appium is 1.4.8
working on Eclipse IDE with latest Maven, TestNG and selenium Libraries.
can anybody help?

Comment: Can you please share code which you have written to specify all capabilities and app. invoke?

Comment: AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), new DesiredCapabilities());

Comment: I would like to see full code about all capabilities and driver declaration. Can you please add whole code by update your question?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure toy are passing correct hub url while creating driver object.

like below
*IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), new DesiredCapabilities());*

The capabilities are read from the application uploaded.

the url should be: http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub and empty desired capabilities object.

Comment: I did that, and in iOS case I belive the adress should be "http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub", the 127 is for the Android
still does not work, session issues are related to Appium version and JDK version, do you know if there are any limitation in that part ?

Comment: Currently, AWS Device Farm supports JDK 1.7 and Appium 1.4.1. Can you try that combination?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Make sure you have launched your server. Go to your desktop appium application
Select the OS ( Android , IOS)
Hit Launch